# Метроном на Ruby

Tags: ruby

Не нашел ничего толкового по данной тематике. Я хочу создать простейший метроном. Чтобы он отстукивал в определенном ритме. Не знаю как сгенерировать звук.
Вообще я хочу создать метроном с изменяющейся частотой отстукивания, а именно первую минуту - 70 стуков в минуту, вторую минуту 90 стуков в минуту и т.д. Чтобы можно было задать алгоритм, но это не сложно и я сам с этим справлюсь, самое главное - это генерирование звучания определенной продолжительности и частоты.

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке манипуляций со звуком нет. Ищите гем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой гем для руби ruby-audio 
https://github.com/warhammerkid/ruby-audio

Его код и документация должны тебе помочь.

Comment: Спасибо большое!